# SQL Query to join tables rows only once to match payments to invoices

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have two tables, Invoices and Payments like this:

Invoices:

```
| Vendor | Invoice No | Amount |
|--------|------------|--------|
| V1     | A1         |   1200 |
| V1     | A2         |   1000 |
| V1     | A3         |   1500 |
| V1     | A4         |   2100 |
| V1     | A5         |   1500 |
| V2     | A1         |    100 |
| V2     | A2         |   1100 |
| V2     | A3         |    400 |
| V2     | A4         |    200 |
| V2     | A5         |    600 |
```

Payments:

```
| Vendor | Payment No | Amount |
|--------|------------|--------|
| V1     | P1         |   1000 |
| V1     | P2         |   1000 |
| V1     | P3         |   1500 |
| V1     | P4         |   2000 |
| V2     | P1         |    300 |
| V2     | P2         |    400 |
| V2     | P3         |    400 |
```

I want to join these tables so that for each invoice row, I want to match only one payment row.
For example V1, P1 and P2 both have an amount of 1000, but only the first one (P1) gets matched to invoice A2.
The unmatched should still show below for each vendor like this:

```
| Seq | Vendor | Invoice No | Invoice Amount | Vendor | Payment No | Payment Amount |
|-----|--------|------------|---------------:|--------|------------|---------------:|
| 1   | V1     | A1         |           1200 |        |            |                |
| 2   | V1     | A2         |           1000 | V1     | P1         |           1000 |
| 3   | V1     | A3         |           1500 | V1     | P3         |           1500 |
| 4   | V1     | A4         |           2100 |        |            |                |
| 5   | V1     | A5         |           1500 |        |            |                |
| 6   |        |            |                | V1     | P2         |           1000 |
| 7   |        |            |                | V1     | P4         |           2000 |
| 8   | V2     | A1         |            100 |        |            |                |
| 9   | V2     | A2         |           1100 |        |            |                |
| 10  | V2     | A3         |            400 | V2     | P2         |            400 |
| 11  | V2     | A4         |            200 |        |            |                |
| 12  | V2     | A5         |            600 |        |            |                |
| 13  |        |            |                | V2     | P1         |            300 |
| 14  |        |            |                | V2     | P3         |            400 |
```

Obviously a simple join does not work as both V1, P1 and P2 will match V1 A2

and V1 A2 will appear twice as shown in the following SQLFiddle example:
[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d17b2/4)

How can I achieve the above without resorting to cursors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `row_number()` and `full join`:

```
select i.*, p.*
from (select i.*, row_number() over (partition by vendor, amount order by ?) as sequm
      from invoices i
     ) i full join
     (select p.*, row_number() over (partition by vendor, amount order by ?) as sequm
      from payments p
     ) p
     on p.vendor = i.vendor and p.amount = i.amount and p.seqnum = i.seqnum;
```

Note that this is a very rudimentary way of lining up payments and invoices.  In the real world, the amounts don't generally line up so nicely -- partial payments, advance payments, and so on.

If that ends up being your real question, ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8ba4a/3) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Using seqnum to match does not always work as can be seen this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8ba4a/1). P1 doesn't get matched at all.


Regarding your concern about payments and invoices not lining up nicely in the real world, I agree. In my real case I am actually lining up invoices against invoices from two different systems but I used Invoices and Payments so it is easier to pose the question.

Comment: @unubar . . . It works if you use the code in the question.  I added the SQL Fiddle for that version.

Comment: Thanks for adding the SQL Fiddle. The matching is working as needed. I get the logic better now. The only thing remaining from my original question is to have a seq number as shown so that the non-matched rows for each vendor appear after the same vendor. Now, all the non-matched rows appear separately.

Comment: I modified to get the non-matched rows for each vendor to appear after the same vendor now [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8ba4a/8). Can it be made better?

Comment: @unubar . . . Your expression is fine.  I didn't realize the sequence number is part of the question or I would have included a similar construct.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Out of curiosity, in the reply the code contains this: "amount order by ?". I am not sure if this is correct or something that I don't know of. Afaik, "?" is used in parameterized queries that are called by a program that binds a variable to it.

Comment: @unubar . . . I'm not sure what you are referring to.  This answer does not contain a `?` parameter placeholder.